# how to echo without being executed

Tags: bash, shell, export, echo

I am trying to add echo statements in /etc/profile but they execute.

Example: This is what I wrote

```
echo CURRENTYEAR="`/bin/date +%y`" >> /etc/profile 
    echo  CURRENTWEEK="`/bin/date +%V` " >> /etc/profile
    echo VERSION="$CURRENTYEAR"."$CURRENTWEEK" >> /etc/profile
    echo export VERSION >> /etc/profile



      echo export SVN_HOME="https://example.com/svn/road" >> /etc/profile
      echo SVN_BRANCH="$SVN_HOME/branches/qa_weekly/$VERSION" >> /etc/profile
      echo export SVN_TAG="https://example.cpm/svn/road/tags" >> /etc/profile
      echo export SVN_TRUNK="https://example.com/svn/empire/trunk" >> /etc/profile
     export PATH=$PATH:/road >> /etc/profile
     export SVN_BRANCH
```

Result: what I get

```
CURRENTYEAR=15
CURRENTWEEK=33
VERSION=.
export VERSION
export SVN_HOME=https://example.com/svn/road
SVN_BRANCH=/branches/qa_weekly/
export SVN_TAG=https://example.com/svn/road/tags
export SVN_TRUNK=https://example.com/svn/road/trunk
```

I want it as below in /etc/profile

```
CURRENTYEAR=`/bin/date +%y`
CURRENTWEEK=`/bin/date +%V`
VERSION=$CURRENTYEAR"."$CURRENTWEEK
export VERSION

SVN_BRANCH=$SVN_HOME/branches/qa_weekly/$VERSION
SVN_TAG=$SVN_HOME/tags
SVN_TRUNK=$SVN_HOME/trunk
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why not just open /etc/profile in a text editor and write it all in there?

Comment: I am using chef so I need to add the script there so that it appends to every server I create using chef

Comment: In that case I recommend accepting Glenn Jackman's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Put your strings in single quotes:

```
echo 'CURRENTYEAR="`/bin/date +%y`"' >> /etc/profile
#....^.............................^
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes

> Enclosing characters in single quotes **preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes**. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than multiple echo statements, use `cat` with a quoted here document:

```
cat >> /etc/profile <<'EOF'
CURRENTYEAR=`/bin/date +%y`
CURRENTWEEK=`/bin/date +%V`
VERSION="$CURRENTYEAR.$CURRENTWEEK"
export VERSION
export SVN_HOME="https://example.com/svn/road"
SVN_BRANCH="$SVN_HOME/branches/qa_weekly/$VERSION"
export SVN_TAG="https://example.cpm/svn/road/tags" 
export SVN_TRUNK="https://example.com/svn/empire/trunk"
export PATH=$PATH:/road
export SVN_BRANCH
EOF
```

Quoting `EOF` in the first line prevents any substitutions from occurring in the body of the here document.